# Google Firestore Data is updating simultaneously in two different google accounts

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I was using firestore database in one of my google account while developing my flutter project.
After testing, I moved the project to a another google account and remove my application from older google account. My problem is when I update the data in any of the accounts database, it is mirroring in the other database also. If I update some value using the mobile application also it is reflecting in both database. Any idea why it is happening.??

Comment: have you change the google-services.json in the process? if not, then you have just assign a new member to the project, meaning that it's the same project in both accounts

Comment: What does it mean "moved the project to other google account"? What do you mean by "project" and what do you mean "account"? How do you "removed" app?